# implementing print functionality c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the following to imeplement print functionality and I am getting the following error:

```
Error   1   'Print.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override   C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Print\Print\Form1.Designer.cs    16  33  Print
```

Below is my code. I am not sure as to why it gives me this error message. I have searched online for the answer but could not find any viable solution. Any help wpul be very very much appreciated folks.

```
namespace Print
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.printForm1 = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm(this.components);
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // printForm1
            // 
            this.printForm1.DocumentName = "document";
            this.printForm1.Form = this;
            this.printForm1.PrintAction = System.Drawing.Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPrinter;
            this.printForm1.PrinterSettings = ((System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings)(resources.GetObject("printForm1.PrinterSettings")));
            this.printForm1.PrintFileName = null;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(97, 69);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm printForm1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you deleted or renamed the `Form1` class in `Form1.cs`.

`Form1.Designer.cs` contains a `partial class` which assumes that the other half of the partial class is declared as inheriting `Form`.

If you break the other half, the compiler will think it's a standalone class that inherits `object`, and that will break the code that relies on the base class.